# Can't generate XML sitemap

Tags: php, xml

I have written some PHP code for generating a sitemap. This code was working well prior to a VPS problem that forced me to reinstall the operating system (and update my VPS). Now the same code does not generate the desired sitemap1.xml in the root directory.

```
function write_xml($url,$priority = 0.7)
    {
    global $handle, $counter, $file_number, $filename;

   if($counter == 50000)
        {
        $file_number++;
        $counter = 0;
        // Attach end of file, and close it here.
        fwrite($handle,"</urlset>\n");
        fclose($handle);
        }

    if($counter == 0)
        {
       // Open next file here.
        $filename = "sitemap" . $file_number . ".xml";
        $handle = fopen($filename,"w+");
        fwrite($handle,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n");
        fwrite($handle,'<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . "\n");
        }
    if($url != "" && $url != "END")
        {
        fwrite($handle,"\t <url>\n");
        fwrite($handle,"\t\t<loc>$url</loc>\n");
        fwrite($handle,"\t\t<priority>$priority</priority>\n");
        fwrite($handle,"\t</url>\n");
        }
    if($url == "")
        {
        fwrite($handle,"</urlset>\n");
        fclose($handle);
        }
// Increment counter for every URL.
    $counter++;
    }
    ?>
```

Please help me understand why the URLs are not written to sitemap1.xml file.

Comment: how about you remove all the fwrite's and append the data to a $variable and at the end you do one write

Comment: i am pretty sure since you reinstalled your os, you have permission problems

Comment: Is there any error? Did u saw the error_log? I think same as ibu , try fixing the folder/file permissions .

Comment: *I* have written some code? http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=141389

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to work fine. The problem must be in the code calling `write_xml`.

Just some minor best practivce - instead of this:

```
if($counter == 50000)
```

it's safer to use:

```
if ($counter >= 50000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a problem with the rights in the root folder. On many configurations the root folder belongs to the account owner, but the apache process is running as user "nobody". You have two choices here:

- create sitemaps into a subfolder having write rights for everyone (0777) and use a rule in htaccess to point the robots in the right direction:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap(.*).xml subfolder/sitemap$1.xml [L]

- create all xml files first on the root , as account owner, than change their rights to be writable by everyone : 0666

Or you may want to generate the sitemap dynamically and have them delivered by a script. In that case their url would be like sitemap.xml?page=1 but you still need to put a rule in .htaccess for it